# I have a regex that returns nil values for excluded words. How do I return nothing instead?

Tags: regex, ruby

Given the following test string:

```
{{one}}

<content>{{two}}</content>

{{three}}
```

I only want to match {{one}} and {{two}}. I have the following regex:

```
{{((?!#)(?!\/).*?)}}|(?:<content\b[^>]*>[^<>]*<\/content>)
```

That matches {{one}} and {{three}}, but also matches a nil value (see: https://rubular.com/r/E4faa6Tze04WnG). How do I only match {{one}} and {{three}} and NOT the nil value?

(that is, the regex should only return two matches instead of three)

Comment: Is it a requirement you use regex for this? This seems more like a template parser of some sort, and IMO it'd be easier to treat it like that, especially if you need to maintain or change it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean but I do want to use regex for this. I have a large body of text and I want to use ruby's gsub method to replace {{tags}} that are outside of the <content> tags.

Comment: I mean using regex for tasks like this is difficult to maintain and extend.

Comment: You say "given the following" and then display three lines of text. Is that a string, three strings, the image of a text file, something else? If it is one or three strings please add quotes so they are valid Ruby objects. Do you want to match `"{{{one}}"`? You say you want to match only `{{one}}` and `{{two}}` and then later only `{{one}}` and `{{three}}`.

Comment: Sorry Cary, that's my test string. I edited that part above for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from your comment:

> I have a large body of text and I want to use ruby's gsub method to replace {{tags}} that are outside of the `<content>` tags.

This regex should do, what you need:

```
(^{{(?!#|\/).*}}$)
```

This matches both `{{one}}` and `{{three}}`, and similar interpolations à la `{{tag}}`, except those: `<content>{{tag}}</content>`.

---

> Can I ignore only  tags specifically and not other tags? For example, I tried it with  tags here: rubular.com/r/jTKxwjNuKoSjgN, which I don't want to ignore.

Sure thing. Try this one:

```
(?!<content>)({{(?!#|\/).*?}})(?!<\/content>)
```

If you need an explanation of how and why this regex works, you can take a look at the explanation section here: https://regex101.com/r/d4DEK1/1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing it in two steps to accomodate more complex strings. I have assumed that the strings "one" and "three" are to be extracted from the following string.

```
str = <<-_
{{one}}
<content>cats {{two}} and <content2>{{four}}</content2> dogs</content>
{{three}}
_
```

```
r0 = /
     <          
     ([^>]+)    # match >= 1 characters other than '>' in capture group 1
     >
     .+?        # match one or more characters lazily
     <\/        # match '<' then forward slash
     \1         # match the contents of capture group 1
     >
     /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

r1 = /
     (?<=\{\{)  # match '{{' in a positive lookbehind
     [^\}]+     # match any number of characters other than '}' 
     (?=\}\})   # match '}}' in a positive lookahead
     /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
str.gsub(r0, '').scan(r1)
  #=> ["one", "three"]
```

The first step is:

```
str.gsub(r0, '')
  #=> "{{one}}\n\n{{three}}\n"
```

This of course works if the second line of the string is simply

```
"<content>{{two}}</content>\n"
```

The two regular expressions are conventionally written as follows.

```
r0 = /<([^>]+)>.+?<\/\1>/
r1 = /(?<=\{\{)[^\}]+(?=\}\})/
```

Comment: Great explanation and another great way to approach it! Thanks for breaking down parts to the regular expressions. Highly informative. Thank you Cary!!